# PHP - Reading from XML using simplexml_load_file returning no values

Tags: php, sql, xml

I'm currently using 'simplexml_load_file' to read from an XML file. I'm looking to read multiple values and store them in some parameters, which I later use in an SQL insert statement.

I can confirm no errors are being returned. Also I have printed these values outs before performing my SQl statement to ensure something wasn't going wrong there, and the echo prints out nothing. I imagine may syntax may be incorrect with regards to grabbing the values, but I'm unsure. Below is my PHP:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("{$path}/{$email_safe}/{$datafile}.xml");

// Retreive data details for specified activity
$totalTime = $xml->TrainingCenterDatabase->Activities->Activity->Lap->TotalTimeSeconds;
$distance = $xml->TrainingCenterDatabase->Activities->Activity->Lap->DistanceMeters;
$maxSpeed = $xml->TrainingCenterDatabase->Activities->Activity->Lap->MaximumSpeed;
$calories = $xml->TrainingCenterDatabase->Activities->Activity->Lap->Calories;
$intensity = $xml->TrainingCenterDatabase->Activities->Activity->Lap->Intensity;
$trigMethod = $xml->TrainingCenterDatabase->Activities->Activity->Lap->TriggerMethod;

// Store activity details into the 'detail' table
$sqlDetail = "INSERT INTO detail (detailID,TotalTime,distance,maxSpeed,calories,intensity,trigMethod) VALUES (\"$datafile\",\"$totalTime\",\"$distance\",\"$maxSpeed\",\"$calories\",\"$intensity\",\"$trigMethod\")";
$runDetail = mysql_query($sqlDetail) or die("unable to complete INSERT action:$sql:".mysql_error());
```

And here is a snippet of the XML file which I'm attempting to read from:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<TrainingCenterDatabase xmlns="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityExtension/v2 http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityExtensionv2.xsd http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2 http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabasev2.xsd">

  <Activities>
    <Activity Sport="Running">
      <Id>2014-02-17T20:23:52Z</Id>
      <Lap StartTime="2014-02-17T20:23:52Z">
        <TotalTimeSeconds>1585.4799805</TotalTimeSeconds>
        <DistanceMeters>113.5199966</DistanceMeters>
        <MaximumSpeed>1.3720000</MaximumSpeed>
        <Calories>3</Calories>
        <Intensity>Active</Intensity>
        <TriggerMethod>Manual</TriggerMethod>
```

If anyone is able to point out my errors here, It would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Test this: echo $xml-> Activities->Activity->Lap->TotalTimeSeconds;

Comment: This gave me a value! Thank you very much. I don't suppose you know why the 'TrainingCenterDatabase' tag does not need to be referenced?

Comment: If that worked for you, can you accept my answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the sample XML you provided, it seemed that "TrainingCenterDatabase" was not part of the tree--

Change this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("{$path}/{$email_safe}/{$datafile}.xml");

// Retreive data details for specified activity
$totalTime = $xml->TrainingCenterDatabase->Activities->Activity->Lap->TotalTimeSeconds;
$distance = $xml->TrainingCenterDatabase->Activities->Activity->Lap->DistanceMeters;
$maxSpeed = $xml->TrainingCenterDatabase->Activities->Activity->Lap->MaximumSpeed;
$calories = $xml->TrainingCenterDatabase->Activities->Activity->Lap->Calories;
$intensity = $xml->TrainingCenterDatabase->Activities->Activity->Lap->Intensity;
$trigMethod = $xml->TrainingCenterDatabase->Activities->Activity->Lap->TriggerMethod;
```

To this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("{$path}/{$email_safe}/{$datafile}.xml");

// Retreive data details for specified activity
$totalTime = $xml->Activities->Activity->Lap->TotalTimeSeconds;
$distance = $xml->Activities->Activity->Lap->DistanceMeters;
$maxSpeed = $xml->Activities->Activity->Lap->MaximumSpeed;
$calories = $xml->Activities->Activity->Lap->Calories;
$intensity = $xml->Activities->Activity->Lap->Intensity;
$trigMethod = $xml->Activities->Activity->Lap->TriggerMethod;
```